@import with media query still being retrieved
When importing a css file with @import and a media query, the file is retrieved even if the media query doesn't match. For example, the code below.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
  <button>Click me</button>
  <style>
    @import url('styles.css') print;
  </style>
</body>

</html>

The styles.css file is always retrieved, while the media query print does not match. This happens is all browser.
Here is a reproduction
